# Error Import Jobs Talend Data Integration 8

Tags: bigdata, etl, talend

After importing the jobs on Talend 8 Desktop, when I try to open any job that was created, I get this error here: JsonloException setting field 'storedValue' on target: Property: nullwith value: {}

I exported the talend jobs from a notebook to place on another notebook, apparently the import was done but the jobs do not open, the error occurs